# $or Operator in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using the `$or` operator in mongoose for searching through the `name` and `description` fields of the database. I want to check if the `queryWord` string contains any part of the database field(s). This is the code I am using:

```
const query = {
$or: [
  { name: `/${body.queryWord}/i` },
  { description: { $regex: `/${body.queryWord}/i` } },
 ],
};

Food.find(query, (err, data) => {
 if (err) {
  res.status(500).send(err);
 } else {
  res.status(200).send(data);
 }
});
```

But it returns, only, an empty array!

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because you wrap the regular expression in ``, which is understood as a string. You can try this way:

```
const queryWordRegex = new RegExp(body.queryWord, "i");
const query = {
$or: [
  { name: { $regex: queryWordRegex  } },
  { description: { $regex: queryWordRegex  } },
 ],
};
```